# What is THE shortest English verb?

Tags: verbs, vowels

I have heard that two letter verbs are the shortest verbs in English. Is this totally true? Are any of the letters official recognized as verbs?

Comment: Probably _E_, meaning to receive a grade of "E" (was "F") in a class. _He thinks he's gonna pass, but I bet he'll E out calculus_. "E" is pronounced /i/, and that's a high front tense vowel, as short as any other English vowel.

Comment: @JohnLawler: That's an interesting definition of "officially recognized word" you've got there. Most dictionaries either claim that "E" isn't a word at all (although some claim is a noun shorthand for ecstasy). I certainly can't find any that claim it is a verb meaning "to be awarded an E in an exam"

Comment: There's no such thing as an "officially recognized word". You've got it backwards: dictionaries don't determine what the language is; the language determines what's in the dictionaries. It's not a matter of definition; who would do the defining? [The Academy](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html)?

Comment: I've heard "U" used for "make a U-turn", as in "we need to go back, can you U here?". Perhaps this is not (yet...) in common use.

Comment: WHen I was writing my dissertation back before mere graduate students had word processors I often had to x out entire pages.

Comment: X, meaning cross, also in Ped Xing.

Comment: *P* is used as a verb also.

Comment: 1: "Officially unrecognized words" don't count for this OP's question. Even if it's in the Urban Dictionary online, it's not "officially recognized by The Academy". 2: _E out_ & _X out_ are phrasal verbs. However, I can imagine (I usually hate thought experiments) that students say things like _I **B-ed** my math test_.

Comment: At http://www.railpictures.net/showphotos.php?locomotive=EMD%20FP9A , in railspeak: _KCS 1 has arrived at Whiterock Junction to be Y'ed. From here she will back down the Garland main for about 10 miles before heading north back to Wylie._ Looks like you can Y KCS 1 at least.

Comment: Oh, and is the **w** in the English word _cwm_ (from the Welsh, of course) a consonant?

Comment: _I have heard that Go is the shortest verb in English._ Where did you hear this heresy? What makes _go_ shorter than _be_? _Be_ is a verb. So is _is_. So is _ax_. One could make an argument for [OK](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/OK?q=ok), too.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Degenerating to existential "what is an English word" type statements isn't helpful to the OP. The OP clearly is asking what is the shortest *common usage* word is, hence why he wants an "official" word. Yes. There's no official body that controls English. But you can use a dictionary to find out whether a word (like 'Y') is used in an exceptionally narrow field like railways, or is used by every man on the street like "go". 'E' and 'Y' are used so infrequently that most English speakers would not recognize them as a word in their own right. "Go" OTOH is clearly a word.

Comment: So, it's a matter of opinion whether a word is a word, and it's a matter of opinion what "short" (not to say "shortest") means (number of letters, size of letters, amount of ink used, width of lowercase, duration of sound, ...). So that answer is a concatenaton of opinions.

Comment: @Matt: Dictionaries in general have very little to say about how "common" words are, apart from occasional labels like _"Obs.", "Archaic", "Baseball"_ or _"Rare"_. Furthermore, I disagree with your assertion that John's comment "isn't helpful to the O.P." There's no point in debating "Which verb is shortest?" until we first define what a word is. That's not "degenerating," that's getting to the crux of the matter.

Comment: @J.R. I guess I didn't mean that it is the shortest verb, just the shortest action verb. I should have been more clear. I was thinking in the terms of the shortest sentence, which has to have an implied *you*.

Comment: Fixed that in the questions

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns trivia rather than useful advice on usage.

Answer (score 6):

From OED:

x, *v*.

Pronunciation:  /ɛks/

Forms:  Pa. tense x-ed, x'd.

1. *trans*. To supply with x's in place of types that are wanting. rare—1.

1849   E. A. Poe X-ing a Paragrab in Wks. (1856) IV. 265   ‘I shell have to x this ere paragrab,’ said he to himself, as he read it over... So x it he did, unflinchingly, and to press it went x-ed.

I'm sure there are others.

Comment: This answer makes me wonder why the O.P. asked about vowels specifically, as opposed to any single-letter verb. (Maybe the O.P. should x out the word _vowels_, and change it to _letters_.)

Comment: I think many English learners are taught that a syllable is defined by the inclusion of at least one vowel, & that a word must have at least one syllable.  Also there is the idea that, for example, /ɛks/ is somehow an improper pronunciation of the symbol "x".  I propose that "." can stand for "stop", and be so pronounced.  I now assert "." as the smallest English verb.

Comment: I wondered about symbols, too, but that's blurring the line between English and mathematics. There are also numbers like "86", which, in the restaurant business, can function as a verb meaning "declare we are out of," as in _"86 the lobsters for the night"_ as the chef drops the last one into the pot.

Comment: I said vowels because I have been taught that all words must have a vowel (such as *a* and *I*). It appears I am mistaken.

Comment: Hmm...I think that *x* is definitely the most plausible--I have heard it used before, such as "x out that sentence" or even in Windows "x out that window". Do you think it needs an object? For example, would it be proper to say "[you] X."?

Comment: Ian: I don't know if one would say, "[You] x," but one might conceivably use "X" by itself in a dialog, short for, "X [it]." Consider this hypothetical dialog, between a writer and her editor: "What should I do with this paragraph?" "I think you should x it." "And this one?" "X it." "This one?" **"X."** "And this last one?" "That one's okay; I think you should leave that one as it is."

Answer (score 3):

"*Go*" isn't any shorter than "*do*" or "*be*", so you heard a partial truth. The whole truth is that "*Go*, *do*, and *be* are the shortest verbs in English".

None of the vowels is officially recognized as a verb: an indefinite article -- *a*; a personal pronoun --*I*; an interjection -- *O* (variant of *Oh*); a texting abbreviation for *why* -- *y*; and a texting abbreviation for *you* --*u*.

Answer (score 0):

None of the single vowel combinations are verbs - 'A' is an article, 'O' is an exclamation, and 'I' is a pronoun. Depending on how far you want to stretch the definition of "officially recognized" 'U' is a common shorthands for "you", and are hence is a noun and noun/adverb/exclamation respectively. None are verbs, and the others are not standard English words.

The shortest verb, technically, is 'X':

> X (v):
>
> Mark or make a sign with an X.

Although it is reasonably uncommon.

There are, however, several two-letter verbs in common usage - such as "be", "do" and "go".

Comment: Matt: You should x this out; you erred by examining only the consonants. :^) See commonhare's answer.

Comment: @J.R. In fact, I should have examined the consonants harder. Even so, I think the whole "'X' as a verb" is a little spurious, even if it's mentioned by the OED. Why can't I 'Q' a document with a 'Q'? or 'F' an exam paper with an 'F'? "be", "do" and "go" are at least in common general English.

Comment: Whenever a question asks about English superlatives (e.g., What's the shortest verb, what's the longest word, etc.), then the question inherently lends itself to what you call "spurious" answers.

Answer (score 0):

*eye*, as in "I've been eyeing that cookie for a while now," is pronounced simply as the diphthong **/aI/**. Then you have *ooh*, "to make the sound *ooh*," which is pronounced as a single monophthong **/u/**. And how about *err,* which, depending on the dialect, might come out as a single rhotacized vowel.